# org.json.JSONObject : automatically converts Empty String to Zero

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, org.json

I have a String :

```
jsonStr = {111:{Param1:1, Param2:, Param3:} ,112{Param1:, Param2:, Param3:}};
```

Which I am trying to convert into JsonObject (org.json.JSONObject).

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

It is converting into valid JsonObject but 'Param2' which is having nothing as value, getting it value converted to 0.

I want that if a parameter is having empty value, I should get null when i access object :

```
jObj.getString('Param2').
```

Please share some pointers in this scenario.

Comment: Can't you give it the value you want before converting it?

Comment: That is already being tried but as we are receiving string from external application, we cant force them to set any value to indicate null.